# ItemDelegate vs ProxyModel Subclass

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qitemdelegate, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm have to create a form where some questions will be taken from the db. Each question will have two radioButtons (Yes / No), a label "Explain..." and a textEdit.
Firstly I created this in a QScrollArea, where for every question in the db (taken with QSqlTableModel) all the necessary widget were created and put into the layouts.

Now I think I would better do it in a QListView, where an item will be all the question = its information (question + 2 radioButtons + label + textEdit + its Layouts). I thought I could easily do it with QAbstractItemDelegate, so I created a subclass for it, but I am having some problems though. 
The question are not shown at all, even are its informations. Should I use a subclass of ProxyModel instead? I found a very useful [checkableProxyModel](https://gitorious.org/checkableproxymodel)!  subclass which added a checkbox for every item in a model, and I thought if it was possible to add a checkBox, maybe it is possible to add all this information?

Any idea?

Comment if you need any code.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt Model & View classes only provide the ability to have an additional checkbox, by including [Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) in the flags return value of [QAbstractItemModel::flags()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags). The Qt MV classes however don't allow any custom widget like radio buttons to be used as the delegate.

One way to render a widget would be using [QStyle::drawComplexControl()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawComplexControl) in your QAbstractItemModel::paint() reimplementation, but that gets difficult when you have multiple widgets like in your case, and it doesn't handle interaction.

A better way would be to use [QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget), but see [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29847) for a Qt developer talking about the performance implications.

Comment: I found out it was possible even adding a radio button, but anyway it was far more complexed and instead of making it more dynamic, I will have just a complex code :) so it is useless i guess. I think I can do it in a qTreeView, to have the question as a parent and the description as a child of the question, and a second column for a checkbox Y/N. I will have a look at the docs you recommended. Thank you  @tmcguire !